# What is causing a dismissed google signin result in my React Native Expo project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to implement google sign in in my react native project.

I created the project with expo.

I tried re-reading the documentation all day, but I'm still stuck with a problem.

When I run the app in Expo Go, the signin works as expected, perfectly fine.

However, when I build the standalone app, start it, try to signin, I get a dismissed response after the signin prompt closes, and I just can't get why.

I made sure the google developer console and the useAuthRequest function have the same client ids.

I also tried setting useProxy and showInRecents properties to true in the promptAsync method options, but it doesn't make a difference.

What am I doing wrong, or what can possibly cause a dismissed request result?
(I tried to paste the code that might be relevant to the problem only)

```
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import React from "react";

interface User {
  name: string,
  email: string,
  picture: string,
}

export default function App() {

  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = React.useState<string | null>(null);
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = React.useState<User | null>(null);
  const [txt, setTxt] = React.useState("");

  WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
    androidClientId: 'android client id, copied from google developer console',
    expoClientId: 'web client id 1, copied from google developer console',
    webClientId: 'web client id 2, copied from google developer console'
  }, );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTxt(response?.type!)
    if(response?.type === "success") {
      setAccessToken(response.authentication!.accessToken);
    }
  }, [response])

  const getUserInfo = async () => {
    let userInfoResponse = await fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me", {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` }
    });


    userInfoResponse.json().then(userInfo => {
      setUserInfo(userInfo);
    });


  }


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{txt}</Text>
      {showUserInfo()}
      <Text>{accessToken}</Text>
      <Button title={accessToken ? "Get user info" : "Login"} onPress={accessToken ? getUserInfo : () => promptAsync({useProxy: true, showInRecents: true})} />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you try "yarn ios" command? Please check and try compiling the app